# Getting gnome keyring credentials on the command line, not knowing the SERVICE + USERNAME

Tags: gnome-keyring

I'm trying to programmatically get the key which my Chrome browser uses to encrypt its cookies. But whatever tool I consider, it appears that I need to know a service and a username (or an 'attribute' and 'value'). How can I find discover these values?

([In Chrome v11, the key is stored in the gnome keyring](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/53.0.2785.100/components/os_crypt/os_crypt_linux.cc#80) (I think?), and indeed, when I fetch the key using the "Passwords and Keys" GUI, it decrypts the cookies accurately.)

[image]

I've tried my best guess, running `keyring get 'Chromium Safe Storage' $(whoami)`, but that outputs nothing and returns an error code of `1`. I've also tried `keyring get keyring.backends.SecretService.Keyring chromium`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about SERVICE or USERNAME still, but here is the usage for `secret-tool`:

```sh
secret-tool lookup application chromium
```

How would you know what attribute+value pair will match the Chromium Safe Storage entry?

```py
# Python 3
import secretstorage
connection = secretstorage.dbus_init()
collection = secretstorage.Collection(connection)
for item in collection.get_all_items():
     print('%16s %s' % (item.get_label(), item.get_attributes()))
```